# How can I schedule a device block from access to the internet on my Asus RT-AC68U router?

Tags: router, scheduled-tasks, blocking

Yes I am aware of the Time Schedule feature under Parental Control. However, that feature cannot block one of my devices for some reason. It can for other devices on my network.

Comment: If this is possible on your device you most likely will have to use a third-party (community) firmware like OpenWRT but support for that firmware is device specific

Comment: I don't want to go through the trouble of flashing a 3rd party firmware at present without knowing for certain that it will work.

Comment: A work around would be to connect all other devices to another router, then use parental controls, to block the MAC address of that router.  Otherwise, based on what you have indicated, the OEM firmware of your device does not support the schedule blocking of multiple devices.

Comment: That device is already set to be blocked by MAC address under Parental Control yet it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is quite old question, the answer may still help someone.

The schedule should work.
If it does not, are you sure the device maintains the MAC address? If it is a mobile phone, it is very possible that it uses an arbitrary MAC address for every new session (i.e. re-connection). The name of the device may remain but the schedule happens based on the MAC address.